# Delay trigger for right click event on windows tablet

Tags: windows, tablet, right-click

on a tablet you trigger the right click-event by touching the screen and by holding it - after maybe 2 seconds.

Where can I set the property to delay the trigger (maybe up to 5 seconds)? Do i have to set it programmatically (prefer c#) or are there other possibilities (Registry)?

Tablet: HP Elitepad 1000 G2

Thx for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Control Panel > Tablet PC Settings > Other > Pen and touch > Touch > Press and Hold > Settings > Right-click mode activation